# Scaling a sprite with css/sass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm using sass image sprites and span tags to create images. I'm now having a problem resizing these images. It appears that using `background-size` somehow applies to the whole sprite atlas and not just the chosen sprite.

How can I resize the sprite images?

Example code, I setup sprites like this:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites/sprite-img";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

And then I use them with a class tag, or I create new classes which directly mention them in the scss file:

```
.more span.right-icon {
  @include icons-sprite('item-more');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around it - the image is considered as a whole and the sprites are just logic inner guides.

You could, however, recalculate the `image-position` according to any changes you apply to the `background-size` respectively.